# laravel model find return null for existing id

Tags: php, laravel, activerecord, model, laravel-5.6

I am facing this issue of model find for existing id that is returning null and showing below error.

> Creating default object from empty value

This id exists in the database but it is still returning null.

```
$model = Shoppinglist::find($id);
$model->buy_it = 1;
$model->qty= $qty;
$model->save();
```

This problem starts when I change the columns qty type from into(10) to float because I want to save floating values in db column.
I have spend hours on this issue and still unable to solve.
I have check by providing static id value in-place of variable $id.
I have check by converting $id to int.

Comment: so if you dd($model); right after the find statement you get null?

Comment: what does `dd($model)`  show?

Comment: dd($model)  return null.

Comment: what does `echo  $id` show?

Comment: We need a schema of your database and the code of your Model for this.

Comment: Please post your database schema with your model class.

Answer (score 2):

Before using `find($id)`, you should check the key in your table is primary key, otherwise, you can use `where('id', $id)->get()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases to consider in this issue.

My suggestion first is that explicitly declare the primary key in your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'shopping_list_id'; // or 'id' depending on your specified primary key
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether have you used soft deletes trait and your deleted at column is empty in db and ensure that you have made id as primary key in table  and at last place

```
protected $table = "shopping_lists"
```

in your ShoppingList model file

or check whether your model name and table name matches

Answer (score 0):

maybe the value of `$id` is treated as string so try using `intval()`

```
$model = Shoppinglist::find(intval($id));
$model->buy_it = 1;
$model->qty= $qty;
$model->save();
```

or if you need new method you can try using `first()` or `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`

```
$model = Shoppinglist::first(intval($id));
$model = Shoppinglist::findOrFail(intval($id));
```

Answer (score 0):

In most scenario user create differnent primary key like shoppinglist_id instead of id then find function not working you have to add

```
protected $primaryKey = 'shoppinglist_id';
```

You have to add above code in your model Shoppinglist

**Alternatively**

```
$shopping = Shoppinglist::where('table_priamry_key', $id)->first();
dd($shopping);
```

if you are using soft delete then add software delete in where to get the result

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone who stumps on this later. I had the same problem that was originating from my model's primary key. I set the `$primaryKey = another_field` which was not pointing to the `id` I was trying to get. So all I did was set `$primaryKey = 'id'` and everything was cool. Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

If you have none set  ***$primaryKey*** property in your ***MODEL***, it's going to assume **id**.

The find() method finds the Model by it's $primaryKey property.
So if you want change default primary key in Eloquent you need this.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'email';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using `softdeletes` for the row you are retrieving might have been deleted. Happened to me, got the same error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30843757)